# Replace data source in a connexion string

Tags: powershell

In this string:

```
"Data Source=srv1-a.be.com;Initial Catalog=db1;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

I would like to replace the data source name by localhost whatever the data source name, with PowerShell script.

With the following code the string is truncated after localhost!
I get the result → `Data Source=localhost`.

```
"Data Source=srv1-a.be.com;Initial Catalog=db1;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;" -replace  '(?<grp1>Data Source=)(.*)', '${grp1}localhost'
```

The result should be:

```
"Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=db1;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified your `-Replace` operation slightly:

```
"Data Source=srv1-a.be.com;Initial Catalog=db1;Provider=SQLNCLI11;Integrated Security=SSPI;" -replace '(?<=Data Source=)[^;]+','localhost'
```

I am using a positive lookbehind `(?<=)` to find the `Data Source=` string and set the position at that location (character just after the `=`). `[^;]+` matches one or more consecutive characters that are not `;` from the current position. Then we are just simply replacing the matched string with `localhost`. As a result, only the server name is matched and updated.